# Json to html table from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, model-view-controller

[image][image]  I have a function that add table rows once the button was clicked and i have a json data i want data to be added to that table but the result says undefined in console can anyone help

```
function addRow() 
{
    var rowCount = $("#detailTable>tbody>tr").length;
    $("#detailTable>tbody").append('<tr><td><input name="ProductName" required></td><td><input name="Qty" class="Qty" required></td><td><input name="Price" required></td><td><input class="total" name="total" readonly></td><td><a class="del" href="#">Delete</a></td></tr>')
    $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ccc");
}
```

I have a mvc where json result is fetched its working fine when i apply to html its not working  can any one help

```
$.get('@Url.Content("~")Home/GetSalesDetail', { invoiceId: salesHeaderData.invoiceId })
    .done(function (salesDetailData) {
        console.log(salesDetailData);
        for (var j = 0; j < salesDetailData.length; j++) {
            var row = $("<tr />")
            $("#detailTable").append(row);
            row.append($("<td>" + salesDetailData.ProductName + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + salesDetailData.Qty + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + salesDetailData.Price + "</td>"));
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: so your console.log(salesDetailData); is printing undefined ???

Comment: no the values was not assigned in table table result is undefined

Comment: Then its easy...  Can you add the JSON output of salesDetailData .. Like JSON.stringify(salesDetailData);

Comment: how can i apply the result to table

Comment: In order to solve your issue I need to see JSON format. So can you pls add output of JSON.stringify(salesDetailData);

Comment: ok i will add the output and json

Comment: json works good json to table is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As object is an array you need to provide index to read it.
it has to be like this

```
for (var j = 0; j < salesDetailData.length; j++) {
  var row = $("<tr />")
  $("#detailTable").append(row);
  row.append($("<td>" + salesDetailData[j].ProductName + "</td>"));
  row.append($("<td>" + salesDetailData[j].Qty + "</td>"));
  row.append($("<td>" + salesDetailData[j].Price + "</td>"));
}
```

give special attention to `[j]` in `salesDetailData[j].ProductName`

Comment: yes its what i am looking thank you so much it helped a lot